Looking for a newer version of "Who Can Kill a Child?", Spanish film that depicts children killing adults on an island
The film starts with two (I think) adults arriving at the island and slowly discovering the truth until they are attacked/killed.
The setting is tropical; it starts with the group of adults arriving by boat, going to an empty bar and hearing a (weird?) transmission from the radio inside the place.
I believe the spoken language isn't English, but I might be mistaken. It might be Spanish.
It's not an amateur movie.
I think it's from the 2000s.
Characters have olive skin and black hair.
I've found this: 
The plot is basically of Who Can Kill a Child? (Wikipedia), but the movie isn't from 1976.

Your description doesn't include the "children killing adults" part. When and how does this happen?

I've found an older film with the same plot (as far as I remember): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Can_Kill_a_Child%3F

I think I may have found it...
Come Out and Play:

Come Out and Play is a 2012 Mexican horror film produced, shot,
  edited, written, and directed by Makinov. The film stars Vinessa Shaw
  and Ebon Moss-Bachrach. Beth (Vinessa Shaw) and Francis (Ebon
  Moss-Bachrach), a young married couple, are on holiday together when
  they venture to a beautiful, but highly remote, island. Beth is
  pregnant and the two are hoping to enjoy their last vacation before
  their baby is born. When they arrive, they notice that while there are
  plenty of children present, the adults all seem to be missing.
  Initially attributing this to the after effects of a recent festival,
  they quickly realize something far more sinister is afoot. The two
  will face terror and unsettling difficult decisions in their quest to
  make it off the island alive. 
It is a remake of Who Can Kill a Child?" (aka Island Of The Damned), a 1976 Spanish horror movie.
reference





This is the movie I was looking for, thanks.

Cool! Glad to help! :)
